# RViz notification on "params modified"

Tags: ros, rviz, parameter, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I want to create a panel in RViz (part of a plugin) and this panel would contain widgets allowing me to create/modify ROS parameters.

Now, as is, my RViz panel will not be updated if the parameter gets modified outside of RViz - the parameter value displayed by RViz will be wrong. Hence my question: is there a ROS mechanism allowing to get notified on parameters value change? ...or another mechanism allowing to sync my panel?

Should I simply setup a 5Hz timer to update my panel? Or is there a better approach?

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211962/rviz-notification-on-%22params-modified%22/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2015-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For parameters that are expected to change, [dynamic_reconfigure](http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure) is generally a better solution. If that isn't an option, I believe you will have to poll for changes (like with a timer as you mentioned).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-06-23**:
Dan's answer is good, but if you must use params, note that if you are using C++ you can reduce the overhead associated with constantly polling the parameter server by using [ros::NodeHandle::getParamCached()](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Cached_Parameters)